# Como passar os dados de uma tabela para outra sendo que uma tem relacionamento?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

eu criei uma tabela pela migration que tem relacionamentos e tenho uma tabela com os mesmos campos (exceto o id incremental) que tem os dados.
Preciso passar os dados da tabela que tem os dados para a tabela que tem os relacionamentos. Fiz um script para isto mas dá erro de foreignkey.
Tem outra forma de copiar?
Obg.

**Edit**

Estrutura Tabela original com dados:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `locais` (
  `CODIGOLOCAL` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `EMPRESA` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DESCRICAO` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `CODIGOASCEDENTE` varchar(14) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `CODIGORESULT` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATAATIVO` date NOT NULL,
  `RESPONSAVEL` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATADESATIVADO` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `CODIGOTIPO` varchar(9) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `TELEFONE` varchar(14) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `CENTROCUSTO` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(70) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENDERECO` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMPLEMENTO` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `BAIRRO` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `CIDADE` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Estrura tabela criada com Migration e relacionamentos:

Estrutura da tabela `localsoriginal`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `localsoriginal` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `codigolocal` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `descricaolocal` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `idempresa` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `codigopai` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `result` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `dataativo` date NOT NULL,
  `datadesativado` date NOT NULL,
  `idresponsavel` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `idtipolocal` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `telefone` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `centrocusto` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `endereco` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `complemento` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `birro` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cidade` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `iduf` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Indexes for dumped tables

Indexes for table `localsoriginal`

```
ALTER TABLE `localsoriginal`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `locals_idempresa_foreign` (`idempresa`), ADD KEY `locals_codigopai_foreign` (`codigopai`), ADD KEY `locals_idresponsavel_foreign` (`idresponsavel`), ADD KEY `locals_idtipolocal_foreign` (`idtipolocal`), ADD KEY `locals_iduf_foreign` (`iduf`);
```

AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables

AUTO_INCREMENT for table `localsoriginal`

```
ALTER TABLE `localsoriginal`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
```

Constraints for dumped tables

Limitadores para a tabela `localsoriginal`

```
ALTER TABLE `localsoriginal`
ADD CONSTRAINT `locals_codigopai_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`codigopai`) REFERENCES `pais` (`id`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `locals_idempresa_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`idempresa`) REFERENCES `empresas` (`id`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `locals_idresponsavel_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`idresponsavel`) REFERENCES `responsavels` (`id`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `locals_idtipolocal_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`idtipolocal`) REFERENCES `tipolocals` (`id`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `locals_iduf_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`iduf`) REFERENCES `ufs` (`id`);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Script

```
<?php

require("../conexao.php");

//carga local
    $sql = "SELECT CODIGOLOCAL, EMPRESA, DESCRICAO, CODIGOASCEDENTE, CODIGORESULT, DATAATIVO, RESPONSAVEL, DATADESATIVADO, CODIGOTIPO, TELEFONE, CENTROCUSTO, EMAIL, ENDERECO, COMPLEMENTO, BAIRRO, CIDADE FROM locais";
        echo $sql;
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while ($f = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
                echo 'entrei aqui';
                $codigolocal = $f['CODIGOLOCAL'];
                $idempresa = 1;
                $descricaolocal = $f['DESCRICAO'];
                $codigopai = $f['CODIGOASCEDENTE'];
                $result = $f['CODIGORESULT'];
                $dataativo = $f['DATAATIVO'];
                $datadesativado = $f['DATADESATIVADO'];
                $idresponsavel = 1;
                $idtipolocal = $f['CODIGOTIPO'];
                $telefone = $f['TELEFONE'];
                $centrocusto = $f['CENTROCUSTO'];
                $email = $f['EMAIL'];
                $endereco = $f['ENDERECO'];
                $complemento = $f['COMPLEMENTO'];
                $birro = $f['BAIRRO'];
                $cidade = $f['CIDADE'];
                $iduf = 1;
                $created_at = '2017-01-16 22:05:17';
                $updated_at = '2017-01-16 22:05:17';
                echo  $codigolocal;

                $sqluplocal="INSERT INTO localsoriginal (codigolocal, idempresa, descricaolocal, codigopai, result, dataativo,                idresponsavel, idtipolocal, telefone, centrocusto, email, endereco, complemento, birro, cidade, iduf, created_at, updated_at) VALUES ('$codigolocal', '$idempresa', '$descricao', '$codigopai', '$result', '$dataativo', '$idresponsavel', '$idtipolocal', '$telefone', '$centrocusto', '$email', '$endereco', '$complemento', '$birro', '$cidade',
 '$iduf', '$created_at', '$updated_at)";
                echo $sqluplocal;
                $resuplocal = mysqli_query($con, $sqluplocal);
    }
//Fim carga local
echo 'fim';
?>
```

O erro que dá é de relacionamento

Comment: Insira a estrutura das tabelas e o script para que o pessoal possa analisar

Comment: Podes remover sua edição que colocastes no campo resposta... As chaves no editor servem para formatar o código...

Comment: é aconselhável vc remover suas edições das respostas...

Comment: Desculpe, não entendo. Pediram para colocar a estrutura e o código. O que está errado?

Comment: É que vc colocou no campo de resposta e o certo é editar na pergunta mesmo como eu fiz... Agora se pode ir nas suas respostas(que não são respostas) e removê-las, pois corre o risco de tomar negativos...Precisa se desculpar naum man....Estamos todos aprendendo...

Comment: Entendi. Estou procurando onde editar a pergunta para remover.

Comment: Acho que agora ficou correto.